# Would Asp.net controls render HTML based on the client?

Tags: asp.net, html, aspmenu-control

I have asp:menu control on my page. Never had any problems with it, until my Firefox was updated to v17.
The asp:menu control generates Table in asp.net 3.5. But I have CssAdapter that generate unordered-list instead. But on FF v17 its not working anymore. IE & Chrome are good. I suspect the refID property for Firefox has something to do!
I am running on Asp.Net 3.5, so there is no RenderMode property available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! That was simple, all I had to do was change browser refID from `MozillaFirefox` to `Mozilla`.

```
  <browser refID="Mozilla">
      <controlAdapters>
          <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
                   adapterType="Test.Controls.MenuAdapter" />
      </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many asp.net webforms controls render based on browser capability, and the detection of browser capability is built on an engine meant to be updatable.

So, you can try updating your browser capability file (also known as browsercaps).  Do this by downloading the latest browsercaps files from here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41420

You can update them machine-wide by putting them in the c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\\CONFIG\ directory and overwriting what's there, or single-app by creating a app_browsers directory at the top level of your web app, and putting the files there.  Note that you can also edit these files if the updates don't cover your scenario and you're unable to find a version elsewhere.